# How to exit for loop once if statement is found true. Python

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement, pyautogui

I am making a script for a game for mining. I am using pyautogui to locate various screenshots of ore veins to mine. But the problem is if my inventory fills up at ore #1, my if statement does not seem to run and is skipped over until the for loop finishes the range. I would like to have the inventory be checked with the if statement after each range integer, and if found to be full exit the function and begin "dropOff()". I have added my function below

```
def mine():
    inventoryFull = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
        "full inv.png", confidence = 0.7)
    print("Is inventory full?")
    if inventoryFull is not None:
        print("Yes, inventory is full. Drop off ore.")
        dropOff()
        
    else:
        print("No inventory is not full. Proceed")
        oreReset()
        
        # i is for the number of ore veins
        for i in range(1, 19):
            # Check inventory again
            if inventoryFull is not None:
                print("Yes, inventory is full. Drop off ore.")
                dropOff()
            
            else:    
                print("Searching for ore #" + str(i))
                oreCoords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
                    "ore" + str(i) + ".png", confidence = 0.5)
            
                if oreCoords is not None:
                    # Get the X and Y of the vein
                    veinX = oreCoords[0] + random.randrange(-3, 3)
                    veinY = oreCoords[1] + random.randrange(-3, 3)
                
                    # Move mouse to vein and click
                    pyautogui.moveTo(veinX, veinY)
                    pyautogui.sleep(0.5)
                    pyautogui.rightClick(veinX, veinY)
                
                    # Mine ore vein action
                    mineOreCoords = pyautogui.locateCenterOnScreen(
                        "mine ore.png", confidence = 0.7)
                
                    pyautogui.sleep(0.65)
                
                    if mineOreCoords is not None:
                        mineX = mineOreCoords[0] + random.randrange(-3, 3)
                        mineY = mineOreCoords[1] + random.randrange(-3, 3)

                        print("Mining ore #" + str(i))
                        pyautogui.moveTo(mineX, mineY)
                        pyautogui.sleep(0.65)
                        pyautogui.click(mineX, mineY)
                    
                        pyautogui.sleep(25)
                    
                    else:
                        print("Mine ore action could not be located...")
            
                else:
                    print("No ore vein could be found.")
```

I have tried using breaks, returns, rearranging the if/else statements, and adding the if statement after the mining portion of the block is completed, "pyautogui.sleep(25)".

Comment: "I have tried using breaks, returns, rearranging the if/else statements, and adding the if statement after the mining portion of the block is completed, `pyautogui.sleep(25)`". Please include the code of the said approaches that you have tried so we can help steer them in the right direction.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

```
i=0
while i<19:
    i=i+1
    print(i)
    if somefunction==True:
        i=20
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.